# CSS Box shadow doesnt work

Tags: jquery, css, shadow

The last attribute in the `.main-container` class is the drop shadow. It works if I manually enter it via firebug, but for some reason it doesn't work at all normally.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="main-container"></div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.main-container{
    background-color:black;
    background: #c9ddf0; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #c9ddf0 0%, #acc7e0 50%, #98bad9 51%, #6a9fd1 100%, #6a9fd1 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#c9ddf0), color-stop(50%,#acc7e0), color-stop(51%,#98bad9), color-stop(100%,#6a9fd1), color-stop(100%,#6a9fd1)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #c9ddf0 0%,#acc7e0 50%,#98bad9 51%,#6a9fd1 100%,#6a9fd1 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #c9ddf0 0%,#acc7e0 50%,#98bad9 51%,#6a9fd1 100%,#6a9fd1 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #c9ddf0 0%,#acc7e0 50%,#98bad9 51%,#6a9fd1 100%,#6a9fd1 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top,  #c9ddf0 0%,#acc7e0 50%,#98bad9 51%,#6a9fd1 100%,#6a9fd1 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c9ddf0', endColorstr='#6a9fd1',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius: 9px;
    border-radius: 9px; 
    border:solid 1px #879eb4;
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-300px;
    margin-left:-300px;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:0px px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/Mfkj4/28/

Does anyone have a css based solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were missing a number in your `box-shadow` rule. It said `px` instead of `0px`. Live example http://jsfiddle.net/Mfkj4/30/:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
```

Comment: `box-shadow:0 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1); It's ok to write zeros without 'px'

Comment: @mat: I agree that you can either write `0` or `0px`. As it is often a personal choice though and he was already using `px` for his zero values I continued to use it in the answer to make it clear what was actually causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You had a couple of problems in your CSS for the `box-shaddow` property

```
box-shadow:0px px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
```

All values are required, you have 1 value of `px` that was killing the process to start. This should be

```
box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
```

Secondly you were missing the `-moz-` and `-webkit-` variations to work across Mozilla and Webkit (Safari & Chrome) as shown at [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/). The final code should be

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
```

You can see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mfkj4/31/) - note that I changed the size of your boxes for ease of view.

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Actually `box-shadow` needs to come **after** the prefixed versions, not before. Otherwise the newer standards implementation will never be picked up, only the older prefixed implementation.